# Request to merge tags [орфография] & [правописание]

Tags: bug, tags, tagging, tag-synonyms, tag

I’ve eventually found out we have two pair of tags: [‘орфография’](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%8f) (‘orthography’) and [‘правописание’](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) (‘spelling’). Both are in use. They obviously should be synonyms.